# Weird Excel bar diagram behaviour

Tags: microsoft-excel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Weird Excel bar diagram behaviour](https://superuser.com/questions/119853/weird-excel-bar-diagram-behaviour)

I have a very simple question. I want to have a diagram with the following table:

```
Apple   30  40  50
Pears   200 300 400
Bananas 10  20  30
```

The weird thing is, when I try to draw a bar diagram the order of the bars changes. So Excel first draws the bananas, then the pears, and finally the apple bar... Is there anyway to tell Excel 2003 to keep the original order?

Thank you very much

Comment: Exactly which type of bar chart: horizontal, vertical, stacked, etc.?

Comment: Duplicate of this: http://superuser.com/questions/119853/weird-excel-bar-diagram-behaviour where I answered it.

Answer (score 1):

For horizontal bar graph the order is: from the bottom to the top. If you want to change it, select category (X) axis > Properties > Scale and check "categories in reversed order".

Comment: Thanks for that, it works but the problem is that also the axis label moves to the top which looks a bit odd... Is there any possibility to just change the order and leave the label where it belongs to?

Thanks!

Comment: All the times I have the same need I solve by adding dummy data series (with only title and no data), ordering the series so that they are according to my wishes and then removing the unwanted labels from the legend.