# Weird Excel bar diagram behaviour

Tags: microsoft-excel-2003, diagrams

I have a very simple question. I wanna have a diagram with the
following table

```
Apple   30  40  50
Pears   200 300 400
Bananas 10  20  30
```

The weird thing, when I try to draw a bar diagram the order of the bars
change. So Excel draws me first the Bananas, the the pears and finally the apple
bar... Is there anyway to tell Excel 2003 that it keeps the order?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Click on the vertical axis to select it. Right-click on it and select "Format Axis...".

In the "Axis Options", check the "Categories in reverse order".

[image]